# OpenCV3 - Accessing label centroids

Tags: c++, opencv

OpenCV3 has a lot of cool stuff. I did some filtering with `connectedComponentsWithStats` accessing the array of statistics but can anyone just show me how to access centroids of each label?

Documentation says that's possible as well but i'm not getting it.

```
Mat stats, centroids, labelImage;
int nLabels = connectedComponentsWithStats(input, labelImage, stats, centroids, connectivity);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`centroids` is a matrix of double with two columns (x, y) and rows equals the number of labels.

You can access it like:

```
Mat1i labels;
Mat1i stats;
Mat1d centroids;
int n_labels = connectedComponentsWithStats(img, labels, stats, centroids);

for (int i = 0; i < centroids.rows; ++i)
{
    cout << "x: " << centroids(i, 0) << " y: " << centroids(i, 1) << endl;
    circle(outputImage, Point(centroids(i, 0), centroids(i, 1)), 3, Scalar(0,255,0));
}
```

If you declared `centroids` as `Mat`, access it like: `centroids.at<double>(i,0)`

Comment: Doubles, ohh ok. So since imwrite is restricted to other types here it is the reason why i can't create the imfile. Thks.